# How to know if laravel has security update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

If laravel is open source, and anyone can view and push "fixes" to the master version, I'm sure people can find some security issues.

How I can be updated if there is any security update in laravel.

Thanks.

Edit:
My question was about to bu updated on any laravel's update and of course security issues.
The solution is to "watch" the repo on git hub and to be updated on any update.
https://github.com/laravel/laravel

Good luck

Comment: wordpress is open source, as well.

Comment: Yes laravel is open source.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is open source. You can see from the commits that open bugs are resolved by any user that tackles it.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commits/master